# Ethereum. Is there a way to know the storage space needed by my smart contract?

Tags: transactions, storage, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

How can I quantify how much storage space (approximately) do I need for Ethereum transactions? Is it per function/ transaction or how is it calculated? any leads on this is appreciated. I am trying to quantify the storage space needed for the transactions created by my smart contract...

Comment: It seems like you're mixing up few different terms together. Can you elaborate on what do you mean by the "storage space" and the "transactions created by my smart contract"? Do you have `contract A` calling `contract B` and need to store the returned values in `contract A`'s storage (and calculate the returned data size beforehand)? Or are you talking about estimating the **payload size** (the `data` field) of a transaction calling a contract function? Do you need the calculation to be done on-chain or can it be off-chain?

Comment: Yes the payload size. I want to estimate how much space is used by my smart contract functions onchain. I don't want to do it onchain. I want to calculate it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to calculate the `data` field size

*(when you're sending a transaction calling a smart contract function)*

The `data` field value could be divided into three parts:

- `0x`
- 4 bytes (8 hex characters) - This is the function signature, it identifies the function that you are going to call.

  - *The value is first 4 bytes of keccak256 hash of the function name and argument types. Example: `transfer(address,uint256)` => `a9059cbb`*
- the rest of data - Arguments passed into the function.

---

The easiest way is to use a library that calculates the size for you. :) For example `web3js` function [encodeFunctionCall()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall).

Example:

```
const result = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    name: 'transfer',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'address',
        name: ''
    },{
        type: 'uint256',
        name: ''
    }]
}, ['0x1231231231231231231231231231231231231231', '1']);
console.log(result);
```

Returns

```
0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000012312312312312312312312312312312312312310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

- `a9059cbb` is the function signature
- `0000000000000000000000001231231231231231231231231231231231231231` is the `address` type (256bit, 64 hex chars) first argument
- `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` is the `uint256` type (256bit, 64 hex chars) second argument

So the result is `0x` and 136 hex characters, which makes 68 bytes.