# Decode JSON RPC request to a contract

Tags: web-scraping, ethereum, solidity, json-rpc, binance-smart-chain

I am currently using some website to read some useful data. Using the browser's Inspect>Network I can see this data comes from JSON RPC requests to (https://bsc-dataseed1.defibit.io/) the public available BSC explorer API endpoint.

This requests have the following format:

Request params:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":43,"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"...LONGBYTESTRING!!!","to":"0x1ee38d535d541c55c9dae27b12edf090c608e6fb"},"latest"]}
```

Response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":43,"result":"...OTHERVERYLONGBYTESTRING!!!"}
```

I know that the `to` field corresponds to the address of a smart contract [0x1ee38d535d541c55c9dae27b12edf090c608e6fb](https://bscscan.com/address/0x1ee38d535d541c55c9dae27b12edf090c608e6fb).

Looks like this requests "queries" the contract for some data (but it costs 0 gas?).

From (the very little) I understand, the encoded data can be decoded with the schema, which I think I could get from the smart contract address. (perhaps this is it? https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0x1ee38d535d541c55c9dae27b12edf090c608e6fb)

My goal is to understand the data being sent in the request and the data given in the response so I can reproduce the data from the website without having to scrape this data from the website.

Thanks.

Comment: Would u take a look at my queston related to `json_rpc` plz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605266/how-to-read-smart-contracts-from-tronscan-org-using-laravel-and-json-rpc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero cost is because of the [eth_call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) method. It's a read-only method which doesn't record any state changes to the blockchain (and is mostly used for getter functions, marked as `view` or `pure` in Solidity).

The `data` field consists of:

- `0x`
- 4 bytes (8 hex characters) function signature
- And the rest is arguments passed to the function.

You can find an example that converts the function name to the signature in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950423/1693192).

Comment: Would u take a look at my queston related to `json_rpc` plz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605266/how-to-read-smart-contracts-from-tronscan-org-using-laravel-and-json-rpc