# Check if msg.sender is a specific type of contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

As it is now, anyone can call the `setMyString` function in the `FirstContract`. I'm trying to restrict access to that function to an instance of `SecondContract`. But not one specific instance, any contract of type `SecondContract` should be able to call `setMyString`.

```
contract FirstContract{
    String public myString;

    function setMyString(String memory what) public {
        myString=what;
    }
}

contract SecondContract{
    address owner;
    address firstAddress;
    FirstContract firstContract;
    constructor(address _1st){
        owner=msg.sender;
        firstAddress=_1st;
        firstContract=FirstContract(firstAddress);
    }
    function callFirst(String memory what){
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        firstContract.setMyString("hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solidity currently doesn't have an easy way to validate an address against an interface.

You can check the bytecode, whether it contains the specified signatures (of the public properties and methods). This requires a bit larger scope than a usual StackOverflow answer, so I'm just going to describe the steps instead of writing the code.

First, define the desired list of signatures (1st 4 bytes of keccak256 hash of the name and arguments datatypes) that you're going to be looking for. You can find more info about signatures in my other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66950423/1693192) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66877556/1693192).

An example in the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/assembly.html#example) shows how to get any address's (in your case `msg.sender`) bytecode as `bytes` (dynamic-length array).

You'll then need to loop through the returned `bytes` array and search for the 4-byte signatures.

If you find them **all**, it means that `msg.sender` "implements the interface". If **any** of the signatures is missing in the external contract, it means it doesn't implement the interface.

---

But... I'd really recommend you to rethink your approach to whitelisting. Yes, you'll need to maintain the list and call `setIsSecondContract()` when a **new** `SecondContract` wants to call the `setMyString()` function for the first time. But it's more gas efficient for all callers of the `FirstContract`'s `setMyString()` function, as well as easier to write and test the functionality in the first place.

```
contract FirstContract{
    String public myString;
    
    address owner;
    mapping (address => bool) isSecondContract;
    
    modifier onlySecondContract {
        require(isSecondContract[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    function setIsSecondContract(address _address, bool _value) public onlyOwner {
        isSecondContract[_address] = _value;
    }

    function setMyString(String memory what) public onlySecondContract {
        myString=what;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [ERC-165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165) Standard Interface Detection.

Assuming the contract you want to check implements the ERC165 standard below you can then call supportsInterface to check for compatibility.

```
interface ERC165 {
   function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool);
}
```